# Simple enumeration of discrete simplex

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, simplex

I'm looking for a computationally nice enumeration of the $n$-dimensional discrete simplex
$$\Delta^n_N = \{ x \in Z^{n} | 0 \leq x_i \leq N \, \text{and} \, x_1 + \cdots x_n = N \}$$

I have an easy way to generate all such points but it does not lead to an easily reversible isomorphism. Since the [number of points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Figurate_number) is $\binom{N+n - 1}{n}$, I need to move to a simple computational representation (that is easily reversible), since for large $N$ the mapping is too large to store in the RAM of a typical computer.

For $n=2$ there is an easy and obvious map which may generalize recursively.

Comment: Since the counting yields $\binom{N+n}{n}$ points, there should be a representation in terms of a binary number of length $N+n$ with $n$ digits chosen to be 1 and $N$ to be zero. Mapping that binary representation to decimal (or perhaps hexadecimal) seems decently efficient; the question is whether going to the binary rep. is easily reversed.

Comment: Actually, small complaint: Isn't it $\binom{N+n-1}{n}$ points?

Comment: Yes, I'll edit the question.

Comment: This StackExchange answer may be of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4755949

Comment: That's essentially the same generator of the points that I use, but I don't see how to turn that into a nice bijection to $\{1,2, \ldots, \binom{N+n-1}{n} \}$.